# DateTimeOffset TryParse not accepting valid datetime - C# OWIN implementation

Tags: c#, owin, datetimeoffset, tryparse

I'm using C# OWIN framework for authentication and I have the TokenEndpoint override method which converts IssuedDate & ExpiresDate in the proper format, so I have used DateTimeOffset.TryParse method to check and return datetime, so now the issue that I 'm facing is really strange, one of the service works properly that returns true for the method DateTimeOffset.TryParse while the other service returns false even though both are passing the same date format. Earlier I used DateTimeOffset.Parse and it failed with the reason 'string was not recognized as a valid datetime.' so I changed to DateTimeOffset.TryParse to handle error but I 'm still not able to find the root cause.

```
 public override async Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                DateTimeOffset result;
                if ((property.Key.Equals(".issued") || property.Key.Equals(".expires")) && DateTimeOffset.TryParse(property.Value, out result))
                {
                    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, result.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                }
                else
                {
                    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Both the services passes date in the below format.
Sun, 07 Mar 2021 11:31:14 GMT
Sun, 07 Mar 2021 11:32:44 GMT

Please check the snapshot[image]

Comment: *Earlier I used DateTimeOffset.Parse and it failed with the reason 'string was not recognized as a valid datetime.'* - can you show us the exact date string which was throwing that error? Try to hunt down that string because that sounds like the root cause

Comment: @haldo I have attached in the snapshot and in my question "Sun, 07 Mar 2021 11:32:44 GMT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the two threads have different [Cultures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0)?

Try to specify the date time format:

```
var result = DateTimeOffset.TryParse(
                "Sun, 07 Mar 2021 11:31:14 GMT", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                DateTimeStyles.None,
                out var date);
```

Or use `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact`.

Comment: Thanks Azeez, that worked, may I know the reason, why it was working for one and not for the other, and what exactly we are doing in your code.

Comment: My guess is that one of the services is using the user's CultureInfo and the other is using the server's CultureInfo. I am specifying `InvariantCulture` for parsing the date so that `TryParse` doesn't depend on the `CultureInfo` of the thread. Read more aobut InvariantCulture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-5.0

Comment: Why guess ?? 

Comment: @Luuk I don't have access to the source code, so I can only guess ‍♂️